# how to enclose combined cells as vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have got a data table like

```
library(data.table)
library(lifecontingencies)

dt <- data.table(cash = c(100,120), Flows = c(110,130),time = c(1,1), 
                 Ids = c(2,2), int = c(0.02,0.04), Rates = c(0.02,0.04),
                 proba = c(0.9,0.8), bilities = c(0.7,0.6))
dt

#   cash  Flows time Ids int  Rates proba bilities
#1: 100   110   1     2  0.02 0.02   0.9   0.7
#2: 120   130   1     2  0.04 0.04   0.8   0.6
```

and want to calculate

```
#presentValue(cashFlows, timeIds, interestRates, probabilities)
```

row-wise. How can I do it automatically instead of manually like so:

```
pV1 <- presentValue(cashFlows = c(100,110), 
                    timeIds = c(1,2), 
                    interestRates = c(0.02,0.02), 
                    probabilities = c(0.9,0.7))
pV2 <- presentValue(cashFlows = c(120,130), 
                    timeIds = c(1,2), 
                    interestRates = c(0.04,0.04), 
                    probabilities = c(0.8,0.6))
result <- c(pV1,pV2)
result
#162.2453 164.4231
```

Comment: You just want to feed the entire row to presentValue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would vectorize your calculation via `apply`:

```
apply(dt, 1, function(x) presentValue(cashFlows = x[1:2], 
                                               timeIds = x[3:4], 
                                               interestRates = x[5:6], 
                                               probabilities = x[7:8]))

# [1] 162.2453 164.4231
```

Note that you can manipulate indexes of row any way you want, for example, `x[1:2]` here stands for first and second cells of a row. You can choose first and fourth cells through `x[c(1,4)]`, or just second cell via `x[2]`

Answer (score 1):

As we are using `data.table`, one approach is to group by sequence of rows and apply the function

```
dt[, .(presValue = presentValue(cashFlows = unlist(c(cash, Flows)),
                  timeIds = unlist(c(time, Ids)), 
                  interestRates = unlist(c(int, Rates)), 
                  probabilities = unlist(c(proba, bilities)))), by = .(Row = 1:nrow(dt))]
#   Row presValue
#1:   1  162.2453
#2:   2  164.4231
```

---

Another approach is to combine the multiple columns into one by `melt`ing and then apply the `presentValue`

```
dM <- melt(dt, measure = patterns('cash|Flow', 'time|Ids', 'int|Rates', 'proba|bilities'),
        value.name = c('cashFlows', 'timeIds', 'interestRates', 'probabilities'))[,
           rn := rowid(variable)][]
dM[, .(presValue = do.call(presentValue, .SD)),
              by = .(Row = rn), .SDcols = cashFlows:probabilities]
#   Row presValue   
#1:   1  162.2453
#2:   2  164.4231
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a minute to understand the presentValue and what it needed but I think this should do what you want.

```
apply(dt, 1, function(row) {
  cashFlows <- c(row[1], row[2])
  tIds <- c(row[3], row[4])
  interestRates <- c(row[5], row[6])
  probabilities <- c(row[7], row[8])
  presentValue(cashFlows = cashFlows,
               timeIds = tIds,
               interestRates = interestRates,
               probabilities = probabilities)
})
```